# Solution for equation of a line with 2 variables ax + by = c works in one case but fails in other case

Tags: c++, equation-solving, diophantine

I am trying to solve **ax + by = n**.

When I put n = 7, it solves the equation correctly as X = 2 and Y = 1.
But when I put n = 1, it does not solve the equation. Even though, this equation has valid integer solution, X = 17, Y = -11. here is my full program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void PrintXY(int a, int b, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i * a <= n; i++) {

        if ((n - (i * a)) % b == 0) {
            cout << "x = " << i << ", y = "
                << (n - (i * a)) / b;
            return;
        }
    }

    cout << "No solution";
}

int main()
{
    int a = 2, b = 3, n = 1;
    PrintXY(a, b, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Output when n = 7:

> x = 2, y = 1

Output when n = 1:

> No solution

Reasoning.
2*(2) + 3*(1) - 7 = 4 + 3 - 7 = 0

2*(17) + 3*(-11) - 1 = 34 - 33 - 1 = 0

Both equations solve to give 0. But what is wrong in my program that is causing it to give "No Solution".

Comment: How to overcome that?

Comment: To pick at nits:  To *solve* the linear equation, you need at least two equations.  To **evaluate** the equation, you need to substitute values for the variables.

Comment: Note: infinity of solutions if `n` multiple of gcd of `a` and `b`, else no solution. One solution is directly provided by the extended Euclide algorithm.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Diophantine equation here. Can be solved, or not..

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I am solving 1 varible, then reprzenting the other variable in terms on first variable.

Comment: So you want to find integer solutions of the underdetermined equation?

Comment: @Sebastian, solving this equation is one of the steps in software that I am unit testing. In the use cases, it is guaranteed that the solution has integer values.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the termination condition:

```
i*a<=n
```

This(n>=a*i) need not be true, and is especially not true in case of the solution (ie X=17, Y=-11). Which seems reasonable - Without any bounds(limits) on the answer(either X or Y) , how would you find the solution to a linear equation(with an infinite possible range) in a closed for loop ?

Comment: I am still only checking valid cases in my program. I will check infinite loop while writing invalid cases.

Comment: I see, okay. Still, the termination condition needs to be less strict for you to hit upon your preferred integral solution.

Comment: Did you mean `Y=-11`? Did you miss a minus sign in your answer?  as per the example a=2, b=3, n=1, `2 * 17 + 3 * (-11) = 1`

Comment: I did, thanks for pointing it out.